# Criteria API - joining two tables throws an exception

Tags: java, database, join, criteria-api

I have a database which contains the AccountOwner table and the Account table. The Account table has a PK "account_number", and the AccountOwner table has the same attribute as a FK. I am trying to join the two tables on this attribute, here is my code:

```
      EntityManager em = emfactory.createEntityManager();          

      CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder(); 
      CriteriaQuery<Account> cq = cb.createQuery(Account.class);
      Root<AccountOwner> aroot = cq.from(AccountOwner.class);

      Join<AccountOwner,Account> ajoin = aroot.join("account_number");

      cq.select(ajoin).where(cb.equal(aroot.get("ClientId"),k.getClientID()));
```

However, this throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:The attribute [account_number] is not present in the managed type 
[EntityTypeImpl@18830730:AccountOwner[ javaType: class banking.AccountOwner descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(banking.AccountOwner--> [DatabaseTable(acccount_owner)]), mappings: 3]].
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.ManagedTypeImpl.getAttribute(ManagedTypeImpl.java:148)
```

I know for a fact that the attribute called exactly this in both the tables, here are the relevant parts of the entity classes:

```
public class AccountOwner implements Serializable {
//...

@JoinColumn(name = "account_number", referencedColumnName = "account_number")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Account accountNumber;
//...

}




public class Account implements Serializable {
//....

@Column(name = "account_number")
private Integer accountNumber;
@Basic(optional = false)

//....
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `accountNumber` instead of `account_number` in `aroot.join("account_number");`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `accountNumber` instead of  `account_number`, as the comment said.